# Read Mutiple Channels of 9 Channel Transmitter Receiver

Tags: arduino

I have 9 channel RF RX/TX,i want to connect 3 motors to it.I am able to connect channel 1 with motor1 but unable to connect channel2 with motor2 simultaneously with ardunio.Pls take a look at code. cant able to rotate motors with different channels

```
    int motor1Left = 7;// defines pin 5 as connected to the motor
int motor1Right= 9;// defines pin 6 as connected to the motor
int motor2Left = 22;// defines pin 7 as connected to the motor
int motor2Right = 26;// defines pin 8 as connected to the motor
int enable = 5;
int enable2 = 10;
int channel1 = 2; // defines the channels that are connected
int channel2 = 3;// to pins 9 and 10 of arduino respectively

int Channel1 ; // Used later to 
int Channel2 ; // store values

void  setup ()
{
   pinMode (motor1Left, OUTPUT);// initialises the motor pins
   pinMode (motor1Right, OUTPUT);
   pinMode (motor2Left, OUTPUT);
   pinMode (motor2Right, OUTPUT);// as outputs
   pinMode (channel1, INPUT);// initialises the channels
   pinMode (channel2, INPUT);// as inputs
  //pinMode (enable, OUTPUT);



   Serial.begin (9600); // Sets the baud rate to 9600 bps


}

void  loop ()
{
  Channel1 = (pulseIn (channel1, HIGH)); // Checks the value of channel1
   Serial.println (Channel1); //Prints the channels value on the serial monitor
  delay(1000);

  Channel2 = (pulseIn (channel2, HIGH)); // Checks the value of channel1
  Serial.println (Channel2); //Prints the channels value value on the serial monitor
  delay(1000);

  if (Channel1 > 1470 && Channel1 < 1500) /*If these conditions are true, do the following. These are the values that I got from my transmitter, which you may customize according to your transmitter values */
  {
    digitalWrite (motor1Left, LOW); // Sets both the
    digitalWrite (motor1Right, LOW);// motors to low
   analogWrite(enable, 100);  
}

  if (Channel1 < 1460) // Checks if Channel1 is lesser than 1300
  {
    digitalWrite (motor1Left, HIGH);// Turns the left
    digitalWrite (motor1Right, LOW); // motor forward
    analogWrite(enable, 100);
    //delay(500); 
    //delay(500);
    //digitalWrite(motor1Left, LOW);
    //delay(1);
}

  if (Channel1 > 1510) // Checks if Channel1 is greater than 1500
  {
    digitalWrite (motor1Left, LOW);// Turns the right

    digitalWrite (motor1Right, HIGH);// motor forward
     analogWrite(enable, 70);
     //delay(500);
    //digitalWrite (motor1Right, LOW);
   // delay(50);
    //digitalWrite (motor1Right, HIGH);


}

  if (Channel2 > 1480 && Channel1 < 1500 ) // If these conditions are true, do the following
  {
    digitalWrite (motor2Left, LOW);// Sets both the
    digitalWrite (motor2Right, LOW);// motors to low
    analogWrite (enable2, 100);
}

  if (Channel2 < 1300) // Checks if Channel2 is lesser than 1300
  {
    digitalWrite (motor2Left, LOW);// Turns the left
    digitalWrite (motor2Right, HIGH);// motor backward
    analogWrite (enable2, 100);
  }
  if (Channel2 > 1500) // Checks if Channel2 is greater than 1500
  {
    digitalWrite (motor2Left, HIGH);// Turns the right
    digitalWrite (motor2Right, LOW);// motor backward
    analogWrite (enable2, 100);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see a couple of problems:

- You mention 3 motors, but there appear to be only 2.
- You print out th value read, but don't have any help to identify which one.  Consider adding "Serial.print("Ch1 = ");" just before the first println to differentiate.
- About line 72, you are have mixed Channel2 and Channel1.
- In both channels, you have some dead zones for your readings.  For example, for Channel 1, what will happen if Channel1 is 1465?  Or 1460 or 1470?   In all those cases none of your "if" statements will fire.  In Channel2 the lower dead zone is much bigger, and the upper dead zone is still there (what if Channel2 is exactly 1500?).

Lastly, it still seems like your motor should have done something.  Maybe it was because Channel 1 was less than 1500.  But if it still doesn't work, check your wiring.

Also, a style note:  You use channel1 to be the input pin to read.  You use Channel1 to be the value read from that.  These are extremely similar looking.  If you had mistyped one, it would be almost impossible to spot.  You should consider naming these in a way that makes it easier to spot a mistake, and more obvious.  For example, channel1 could become pinCh1, and Channel1 could become inpCh1.   Others might suggest even more descriptive names, possibly with the first letter indicating data type.  e.g.,
  int iChannel1_PinNumber;
  int iChannel1_InputValue;